# unhashable type: 'list' in printing Tensorflow vector

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am printing vector and matrix of Tensorflow. It prints `scalar` but shows error for `vector`, `Matrix` and `Tensor`

Code goes below:

```
import tensorflow as tf    
scalar = tf.constant([2])
vector = tf.constant([3,4,5])
Matrix = tf.constant([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
Tensor = tf.constant([ [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
                       [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
                       [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] ])
with tf.Session() as session:
    result = session.run(scalar)
    print (result)
    result = session.run(vector)
    print (result)
    result = session.run(Matrix)
    print (result)
    result = session.run(Tensor)
    print (result)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error with your 4th statement:
Use

```
Matrix = tf.constant([ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] ])
#                    ^ extra parenthesis here
```

instead of

```
Matrix = tf.constant([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
```

Comment: @ShekharKoirala Happy to help. Don't forget to accept and upvote the answer :)